# How to enable access to IPv4 users?

Tags: linux, web-server, ip, ipv6

My router works with IPv6, I tried to open a IPv4 server but due to CGNAT no one could access my web server. I asked to some friends to test it, those without IPv6 couldn't reach it. ReqBin also could'nt reach.

I can access IPv4 servers, but I have shared public IPv4, so it's impossible to do web hosting in it.

**How can I allow IPv4 users to access my IPv6 server?**

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Until a while ago I had no IPv6, that's a new thing in my ISP. It seems that IPv6 is not in CGNAT. So I just tried, and now is working.

Comment: I already talked with the ISP, they even don't know what's "web hosting"

Comment: This would be the solution, thanks for your answer

Comment: Over time, this is what the internet will look like, IPv6 only with  IPv4 transition tech. However, if your organization must do its own hosting via v4, there is no substitute for your own address space.

Comment: @JohnMahowald you're right, but Google doesn't index IPv6-only sites, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already talked with the ISP, they even don't know what's "web
> hosting"

If that was the customer support responsible for your contract, that means you do not have a contract with your ISP that is geared towards *professional use*. Maybe even the entire ISP only serves *consume*r use cases.

**Go get a contract with a company appropriate for your use.** One where it says in the contact that you get both of the versions of IP connectivity you want to use.